# GNOME 3.26 very slow under Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, 17.10

I updated to Ubuntu 17.10 a while back and the GNOME performance was fine except for any games. The fps didn't drop but there was a lot of lag when moving up or down or turning around.
Everything worked fine in 17.04 but unity works fine in 17.10. All tests using Xorg because I can't run Wayland.

I use an NVidia GTX 960 with 2GB vram, an i5 6600@3.9ghz and 16GB system RAM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did You install nvidia driver, and if yes try to disable force(full) composition pipeline because (if enabled) it is said to decrease performance.

Comment: Sorry I'm sort if a newb. Yes I have the NVidia drivers buy I don't know what you mean. I mean how do you do that?

Comment: If You don't don't know than You probably do not have it enabled :). It is option that helps with screen tearing that occurs when You install Nvidia driver but it decreases performance. It is located in Nvidia X server settings on "x server display configuration" tab under "advanced"

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look when I get back in roughly half an hour.